# Using Java8 to find string values in one ArrayList present in another ArrayList using endsWith method

Tags: debugging, java-8

I have following code.

```
public class ComparingTwoLists {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> small = Arrays.asList("AA", "BB");
        List<String> big = Arrays.asList("a.b.AA", "a.b.BB", "a.b.CC");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        Consumer<String> consumer = (String outer) -> {
            Stream<String> stream1 = small.stream();

            Consumer<String> innerConsumer = (String inner) -> {
                if (outer.endsWith(inner)) {
                    list.add(outer);
                }
            };

            stream1.forEach(innerConsumer);
        };

        Stream<String> stream2 = big.stream();
        stream2.forEach(consumer);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

I am trying to find out if string values in **small** is present in string values of **big** at end of string, using method endWith() method.

Is this efficient way of doing it?

Another problem I am facing in this code is that when I am trying to **debug** this code, I am able to view/inspect the value of **inner**, but cannot view the value of **outer**. Is there a way to check the value of outer while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
big.stream()
    .filter(s -> small.stream().anyMatch(s::endsWith))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```